# As far as meaning, does the omission of the article "the" in this prepositional phrase changes anything?

Tags: articles, difference, definite-article

It is possible to remove the article *the* from:

> In **the** previous chapters, we saw the importance of communication.

to obtain:

> In  previous chapters, we saw the importance of communication.

*the* is used to further specify the nouns that it precedes. That being said, I don't see how the PP containing *the* adds more specificity to  *chapters* when compared with the one without *the*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct with or without **the**, as you rightly said. But for me the meanings are *very slightly* different.

"In **the** previous chapters" *suggests* to me that the author is referring either to *all* previous chapters or at least several *contiguous*  immediately-preceding chapters.

"In previous chapters" is more vague and *could* refer to, for example, chapters 2 and 5 (if this text appears in, say, chapter 7).

The difference in this case is subtle and maybe a little subjective, but it is there. It is not a *concrete* change of meaning but the idea it evokes for a reader is slightly different.